# Select time series grouped by HOUR() with wrap around

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with temperature readings and need to get the average temp for each hour the last 24 hours but "wrapped around" current hour.

I use this statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT HOUR(readAt) pointTime
              , ROUND(AVG(temperature),1) avgTemp 
           FROM TempReadings 
          WHERE readAt BETWEEN DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()) 
            AND temperature IS NOT NULL 
          GROUP 
             BY pointTime;
```

readAt is a timestamp.
I would like the ordered result to "wrap" around current hour, so if I query at 10.01am first row should be 9am the previous day and last row 10am today.

From the above query I get this:

```
+-----------+---------+
| pointTime | avgTemp |
+-----------+---------+
|         5 |    23.2 |
|         6 |    12.9 |
|         7 |    11.6 |
|         8 |    14.3 |
|         9 |    10.4 |
|        10 |    12.5 |
|        17 |     0.0 |
|        18 |    23.3 |
|        19 |    14.4 |
|        20 |    14.6 |
|        21 |    17.1 |
+-----------+---------+

11 rows in set (0.00 sec)                 ------------------ formatted as codes
```

Edit 22.10: I use the following test statements:

```
CREATE TABLE TempReadings (
readAt DATETIME NOT NULL,
temperature FLOAT NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=big5;

INSERT INTO TempReadings VALUES ((NOW() - INTERVAL 13 HOUR), 10);
INSERT INTO TempReadings VALUES ((NOW()), 20);
INSERT INTO TempReadings VALUES ((NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR), 30);
INSERT INTO TempReadings VALUES ((NOW() - INTERVAL 14 HOUR), 40);
INSERT INTO TempReadings VALUES ((NOW() - INTERVAL 16 HOUR), 50);

SELECT * FROM TempReadings;
+---------------------+-------------+
| readAt              | temperature |
+---------------------+-------------+
| 2016-10-21 20:15:38 |          10 |
| 2016-10-22 09:15:38 |          20 |
| 2016-10-22 07:15:38 |          30 |
| 2016-10-21 19:15:38 |          40 |
| 2016-10-21 17:15:38 |          50 |
+---------------------+-------------+e
```

Below statement produces the average sorted by hour but I would like the oldest average to be the first row

```
SELECT DISTINCT(HOUR(readAt)) as pointTime, ROUND(AVG(temperature), 1) AS avgTemp FROM TempReadings WHERE (readAt BETWEEN DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()) AND temperature IS NOT NULL GROUP BY pointTime;

+-----------+---------+
| pointTime | avgTemp |
+-----------+---------+
|         7 |    30.0 |
|         9 |    20.0 |
|        17 |    50.0 |
|        19 |    40.0 |
|        20 |    10.0 |
+-----------+---------+
```

So I would like the order to be (pointTime):
17 (first row), 19, 20, 7, 9 (last)

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function, and rarely appears in conjunction with GROUP BY.

Comment: so you want the interval to be the last 24 whole hours, correct?

Comment: Also, a result set without a data set is next to useless. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @verhie for each hour I need the average per hour

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for the input. Yes I will provide sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `date_format()`:

```
SELECT HOUR(readAt) pointTime,
       ROUND(AVG(temperature),1) avgTemp 
FROM TempReadings 
WHERE temperature IS NOT NULL AND
      date_format(readAt, '%Y-%m-%d %h') BETWEEN
          date_format(now() - interval 25 hour, '%Y-%m-%d %h') and 
          date_format(now() - interval 1 hour, '%Y-%m-%d %h')
GROUP BY pointTime
ORDER BY MIN(readAt);
```

Comment: Please see above the sample data I have provided. Your output produces the same order as my statement

Comment: @jchris . . . My answer didn't have an explicit `ORDER BY`.  That is what is needed.